# Is it possible to change the language of a boostrap table?

Tags: bootstrap-4, html-table

If you make a datatable in boostrap, it will have a search bar and some next and previous buttons but these are in english only see picture. Is it possible to change the language?

[image]

Comment: the keyword you are searching for is `internationalization`  (or i18n for short): https://datatables.net/manual/i18n

Comment: @cloned, thanks a lot. I needed to translate to french and it worked very well.